# Polymer.import calls callback even when path to .html file is invalid

Tags: polymer

I am using Polymer.import to import a web component dynamically. I am writing

```
Polymer.import(['path to .html file of web component'], function () {
    console.log('web component loaded');
})
```

The callback gets called correctly when the path to the HTML file is valid (which is the expected behavior), but it also gets called when the path to the .html file is invalid. I think this is a bug. Shall I raise a bug report for this ?

Comment: I just tried it and seems to be a bug, in the console it says 404 Error Could not import the mentioned .html and runs the callback function when the function should just break.

Comment: Exactly.. I made a temporary fix in my local webcomponents.js and added an error handler to prevent the callback from getting called. Not sure if I should commit it to Github.

Comment: I could really use your code, it's best to file a bug and send a pull to temporary fix it.

Comment: Here is the pull request https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/pull/220 . Let me know if you need any help in integrating the change with your app.

Comment: Thanks @Web Components Novice